# How to use Express router in best practice?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm building TypeScript REST API. Any difference between

```
router.get();
router.post();
router.patch();
router.delete();
----------------
app.use();
app.use();
app.set();
```

and

```
router
    .get()
    .post()
    .patch()
    .delete();
--------------
app
    .use()
    .use()
    .set();
```

?

If so, which one would be the best practice?

Comment: only good thing when u use router.get for example is that you can make your code more modular for example you would have auth.js where you would define your routes and then in main.js you would use that routes like this app.use('/api/auth',require('path/auth.js')

Comment: above is just an example how you can use it. you can make multiple files for different routs, for examle you would do same for posts, etc. this would keep your main.js smaller and everything would be more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pros or cons of using one versus another. Its just different syntax for writing the same thing. It doesn't make any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

I usually leave this job to prettier (Visual Code Extension). But its up to you, no difference at all